# Condition for HTML Helper MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a DateTime variable in Links DB and I want to count up how many links share the client ID where the month in the DateTime variable is the current month.

However I get this error:

> CS1061: 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'BuildDate' and no extension method 'BuildDate' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The view is built by EF6.

Loop in Client View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.client)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.monthlyQuota)
    </td>
                    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Links.Count)
    </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Links.Where(item.Links.BuildDate.Month == Datetime.Month).Count)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TopicTF)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Links Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace LinksDB.Models
{
public class Link
{
    public int LinkID { get; set; }
    public int IdentifierID { get; set; }

    public string Obdomain { get; set; }
    public string Obpage { get; set; }

    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string Anchor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BuildDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ expression is incorrect.

You cannot use `DisplayFor` helper with a complex linq expression (*here trying to get the count with where predicate*)

You may simply render the value of the `Count` method call on `Links` collection property with your where condition. This should work.

```
<td>
     @item.Links.Count(a=>a.BuildDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
</td>
```

Assuming you want to show the count of links of current month ,for the item you are iterating.

Comment: It has to be `DateTime`. See the udpated answer. you cannot use `DisplayFor` with the linq expression with a predicate to filter data.

Comment: Your edited answer works perfectly :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do that in the c# expression `@(10-item.Links.Count(a=>a.BuildDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month))`

Comment: @liamcook, if this solves the problem then mark as solved (click on the gray tick).